# React setState to push all items in array to state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

so I am trying to load all chat messages on page load. The messages are being retrieved just as I want them but I am having a horrible time trying to push all of them to state, I tried using loops etc but nothing seemed to work. This is the code:

```js
const [name, setName] = useState("")
const [room, setRoom] = useState("")
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])

const { room, name } = queryString.parse(location.search)
loadMessages(room).then((response) => {
  if (response.error) {
    console.log(response.error)
  } else {
    console.log(response)
    setMessages([
      ...messages,
      { text: response.message, user: response.sender },
    ])
  }
})
```

I just want to push every object in the response array into the messages state. Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: what does `response` look like in success case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the response is an array of messages, then you should map it and then set the state to it, like:

```
setMessages(response.map(item => ({
    text: item.message,
    user: item.sender
  })
));
```

Ps: also as @George answered, also you should put the `setMessages` on a `useEffect(() => {}, [])` to prevent it to get datas on every update.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I tried mapping over it before but my syntax must have been off. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @PakoszKonrad no problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `useEfect` hook for data fetching.

> The Effect Hook lets you perform side effects in function components
>
> Data fetching, setting up a subscription, and manually changing the
> DOM in React components are all examples of side effects. Whether or
> not you’re used to calling these operations “side effects” (or just
> “effects”), you’ve likely performed them in your components before.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

From your snippet, it would look something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const messages = async () => 
      await loadMessages(room)
      .then(response => {
          if(response.error) {
            console.log(response.error)
          } else {
            console.log(response)
            setMessages([...messages, 
              {text: response.message,
              user: response.sender}
            ]);
          }
       });
    messages();
}, []);
```

Comment: it seems that there is no need to append the messages to state (`[...messages, ...`) , and it's better to set `message` state variable to response messages directly without appending them.

Comment: I actually had this wrapped in useEffect! I badly copied the code. Sorry about that!